# How to Pause exo player on viewpager adapter when activity get paused on pressing home button from activity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, android-viewpager2

I have made enough search before asking this.

I do use exo player in viewpager2 with recyclerview adapter.
I inflate exoplayer from adapter to View pager.
Everything works fine but the video is not pausing when home button is pressed.
I have tried various method to access the player inside view holder also created a interface between adapter and the main activity. The on pause method is working but unable to access the exoplayer view inside the view holder.

I tried to declare exoplayer on main activity but view pager2 does not support child views directly as per the error message.

any help would be useful for all of us.

```
   public class VidViewPagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VidViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder> {


        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
        // private VideoView videoView;
        private ArrayList<GalleryEntry> galleryentries;
        //   String url;
        Context context;



        //  private int[] colorArray = new int[]{android.R.color.black, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark, android.R.color.holo_green_dark, android.R.color.holo_red_dark};

        VidViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GalleryEntry> murl, ViewPager2 viewPager2) {

            this.context = context;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.galleryentries = murl;
            this.viewPager2 = viewPager2;
            this.setHasStableIds(true);
        }



        @Override
        public  VidViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_big_video_test, parent, false);
            return new  GalleryVideoPlayer.VidViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);




        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(VidViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            //   super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

            holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

            Log.d("playposition",String.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()) + "   Viewholder get adapter position" + " Item id position "
                    + String.valueOf(holder.getItemId() + " position of it holder .getposition depricated" + String.valueOf(holder.getPosition())));


            GalleryEntry vidpos = galleryentries.get(holder.getItemViewType());
            url = vidpos.getPath();



            holder.videoView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {

                    try {
                        holder.initPlayer(url);

                    }catch (NullPointerException ex){


                    }

                }



                @Override
                public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
                    try {
                        holder.videoView.getPlayer().stop();

                        holder.releasePlayer();



                    }catch (NullPointerException ex){

                    }
                }
            });

    

        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
            super.onViewRecycled(holder);
            try {
                holder.videoView.getPlayer().stop();

                holder.releasePlayer();

            }catch (NullPointerException ex){

                Log.d("recerror",ex.toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return galleryentries.size();
        }



        // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
            Button button;
            PlayerView videoView;
            SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
            MediaPlayer audioplayer;
            ImageView hiddenimage;
            int currentposition;
            DataSpec dataSpec;


            ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);




                Log.d("viewpager_current",String.valueOf(currentposition));


                relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
                button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnToggle);
                videoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_view);
                hiddenimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.invisible_image);

                audioplayer = new MediaPlayer();

                audioplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();

                videoView.setControllerAutoShow(false);


                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        if (viewPager2.getOrientation() == ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL)

                            viewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);

                        else {

                            viewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }



            public void initPlayer(String url){

                File file = new File(url);
                // holder.videoView.setSource(url);

                Uri content = Uri.fromFile(file);
                dataSpec = new DataSpec(content);


                final FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource();
                try{
                    fileDataSource.open(dataSpec);
                } catch (FileDataSource.FileDataSourceException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
                    @Override
                    public DataSource createDataSource() {
                        return fileDataSource;
                    }
                };


                if(url.contains(".jpg")|| url.contains(".gif")|| url.contains(".jpeg")|| url.contains(".png")){


                    //    videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Uri imgurl = Uri.parse(url);
                    hiddenimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Glide.with(context).load(url)
                            //.apply(new RequestOptions().override(150,150))
                            // .thumbnail(0.1f)
                            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(600,800)
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.delete)
                                    //  .centerCrop()
                                    .error(R.drawable.delete)
                                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)).into(hiddenimage);

                    //   hiddenimage.setImageURI(imgurl);

                }else {

                    hiddenimage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(buildMediaSourceNew(content));
                    videoView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
                    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);


                }

            }




            public void releasePlayer() {

                if (simpleExoPlayer != null) {
                    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                    simpleExoPlayer.stop();
                    simpleExoPlayer.release();
                    simpleExoPlayer = null;

                    videoView.setPlayer(null);
                    videoView = null;
                    System.out.println("releasePlayer");
                }
            }






        }



/////////////////  this is the listener designed to get onpause from main activity. 
        public OnActivityStateChanged registerActivityState() {

            return new OnActivityStateChanged() {

                public void onResumed() {
                    Log.d("SimpleTextListAdapter", "onResumed: ");

                    Toast.makeText(context,"Resumed now",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


                public void onPaused() {


                    View view = getCurrentFocus();



                    Log.d("SimpleTextListAdapter", "onPaused: ");




                    Toast.makeText(context,"Paused now",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            };
        }




    }


//////////////////////////////  Main activity class


public class GalleryVideoPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {

    //  private String TAG = MediaModuleVideoPlayer.class.getSimpleName();
    private ArrayList<GalleryEntry> galleryEntries;

    String url,surl;
    int launchcode, callcount = 0 , modulecode;
    //   VideoView videoView;
    MediaController mediaController;
    ImageButton sharevideo,  deletefile , viewswitch;
    String filePath;
    private TextView vid_count, vid_date;
 
    private int selectedPosition = 0;
    ViewPager2 viewPager;
    Context context;
    int playflag = 0;
    String history_date;
    int mid , pmode = 0;
    boolean isplaying = false;
    VidViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    ImageButton cutstatus , cutav , valarm, sharelater;
    OnActivityStateChanged onActivityStateChanged = null;


/////////  this interface calls on pause on adapter

    interface OnActivityStateChanged{
        void onResumed();
        void onPaused();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smartgalolayer);

 

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.vidviewpagers);
     
        vid_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_count);
        vid_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        viewswitch = findViewById(R.id.viewswitch);
        cutstatus = findViewById(R.id.cutcontent);
        cutav = findViewById(R.id.videostatus);
        valarm = findViewById(R.id.visualalarm);
        sharelater = findViewById(R.id.sharelater);



        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        galleryEntries = (ArrayList<GalleryEntry>) bundle.getSerializable("vidarray");
        selectedPosition = bundle.getInt("position");

     

        pagerAdapter = new VidViewPagerAdapter(this,galleryEntries,viewPager);
        onActivityStateChanged = pagerAdapter.registerActivityState();

        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
     
        setCurrentItem(selectedPosition);




  

        sharevideo = findViewById(R.id.share);

        deletefile = findViewById(R.id.deletefile);

 
        if (launchcode == 1) {
            deletefile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (launchcode == 2) {
            
        }


        sharevideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                saveVideo();

            }
        });



        deletefile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deletefile();
               
            }
        });

        viewswitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setorientation();
            }
        });




        cutstatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


              


                if(surl.endsWith(".mp4")|| surl.endsWith(".3gp")|| surl.endsWith(".mov")||surl.endsWith(".mpg")||surl.endsWith(".gif")){

                   

                    Intent vcut = new Intent(v.getContext(), GalleryStatusCutter.class);

                    vcut.putExtra("curl", surl);

                    vcut.putExtra("ftype", 0);

                    startActivity(vcut);


                } else if(surl.endsWith(".jpg")|| surl.endsWith(".png")|| surl.endsWith(".webp")|| surl.endsWith(".jpeg")){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Supported for images",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } else if(surl.endsWith(".mp3")|| surl.endsWith(".amr")|| surl.endsWith(".m4a")){


                    Intent vcut = new Intent(v.getContext(), GalleryAudioStatusMaker.class);

                    vcut.putExtra("curl", surl);

                    vcut.putExtra("ftype", 0);

                    startActivity(vcut);

                    

                }


            }
        });


        cutav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 

                if(surl.endsWith(".mp4")|| surl.endsWith(".3gp")|| surl.endsWith(".mov")||surl.endsWith(".mpg")||surl.endsWith(".gif")){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"video content",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent vcut = new Intent(v.getContext(), GalleryStatusCutter.class);

                    vcut.putExtra("curl", surl);
                    vcut.putExtra("ftype", 1);

                    startActivity(vcut);

                } else if(surl.endsWith(".jpg")|| surl.endsWith(".png")|| surl.endsWith(".webp")|| surl.endsWith(".jpeg")){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Supported for images",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } else if(surl.endsWith(".mp3")|| surl.endsWith(".amr")|| surl.endsWith(".m4a")){


                    Intent vcut = new Intent(v.getContext(), GalleryAudioStatusMaker.class);

                    vcut.putExtra("curl", surl);

                    vcut.putExtra("ftype", 1);

                    startActivity(vcut);



                }

            }
        });

        valarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        sharelater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent slater = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShareLaterSmartGalleryBackground.class);

                slater.putExtra("curl", surl);

                startActivity(slater);

            }
        });





        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);

                displayMetaInfo(position);
//
                GalleryEntry vidpos = galleryEntries.get(position);


                surl = vidpos.getPath();

                if(surl.endsWith(".mp4")|| surl.endsWith(".3gp")|| surl.endsWith(".mov")||surl.endsWith(".mpg")||surl.endsWith(".gif")){



                } else if(surl.endsWith(".jpg")|| surl.endsWith(".png")|| surl.endsWith(".webp")|| surl.endsWith(".jpeg")){




                } else if(surl.endsWith(".mp3")|| surl.endsWith(".amr")|| surl.endsWith(".m4a")){




                }

//                 playvideo(url);

                Log.d("original", String.valueOf(position));

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if(onActivityStateChanged !=null){
            onActivityStateChanged.onResumed();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(onActivityStateChanged !=null){
            onActivityStateChanged.onPaused();
        }
        super.onPause();



    }

    private void setCurrentItem(int position) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
        displayMetaInfo(selectedPosition);
    }
```

Comment: not sure If I can help with this comment. What I did is created an exoplayer as part of the activity/fragment and passed the player to the adapter. In view holder.bind I tried resetting same player object with different media items & set it to the playerview. this way I can control exoplayer when activity/fragment lifecycle changes

Comment: sure thanks will try this and update you.